# Merging the latest copy of the master into another branch

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to Git and I just started working on a new branch. I want to make sure I have the latest copy of the master on my computer i.e the changes others made in the master, it has to be merged with my test branch. I tried git pull origin master but that only updates my master branch, so how do I ensure that my test branch is also updated? I want to make sure that the changes I made don't accidentally merge with the master unless I actually want to.

Comment: Do you want to merge master into your test branch or just pull the test branch from the remote?

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to switch to the master branch, so

```
git checkout master
```

Now perform `git pull origin master`

Once the master branch is updated you can switch to your test branch and merge

```
git checkout testBranch
git merge master
```

This will update your branch with the latest master.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To start with you should checkout master with

`git checkout master`

Then fetch all the changes with

`git fetch origin`

Afterwards merge the changes with

`git merge origin/master`

### Before merge

```
   C1--C2--C3--C4--C5--C6--C7--C8<--Test
        ^  \                    
     master \oC3--oC4--oC5<--origin/master
```

### After merge

```
   C1--C2--oC3--oC4--oC5<--master & origin/master
           \
            \C3--C4--C5--C6--C7--C8<--Test
```

Now checkout your test branch again

After you checked out your test branch you need to do

`git rebase master`

## Git rebase

---

Git rebase will find the latest common commit between branches `master` and `Test` cut the part Test added and merge it back to the end.

### After rebase

```
   C1--C2--oC3--oC4--oC5<--master & origin/master
                        \
                         \C3--C4--C5--C6--C7--C8<--Test
```